# How to have a node creation form on a separate node creation form?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm on d7 and creating a "how to" site where users create a topic and add individual steps to it. I have a topic content type and a step content type and I connect them together by having an entity reference field on the steps so they reference the topic. I'm looking for a way to have an "add step" form on the topic creation page that will add a step and automatically reference the topic that I am creating. The field collections module gives me some of this functionality, but it makes it all in the one node being created. I need it to be separate content type because I want other users to be able to add steps to the topic after its been created, as well as commenting on specific steps and flagging. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [References dialog](http://drupal.org/project/references_dialog) also. The module extends entity reference field by adding links to add, edit and search (which links are available can be configured) for references through a dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've checked out the References dialog module but unfortunately it goes the opposite direction than I need. Right now I have a reference field on my "step" content type so that there will be steps that reference a single topic. The reference dialog module would require me to add a reference field to my "topic" content type so it  would be one topic referencing many different "steps" and that won't work because I need to be able to create steps outside of the topic creation as well.